# NSIS Installer Application name not displayed right

Tags: windows, nsis, cpack

I built an application with CPack and NSIS and defined a rather long application name (it's for work, so I censored it a bit). When starting the installer the name is cut off. I already tried removing the spaces in the name, adding ' ' to the string for the spaces and removed just one space at the beginning of the name, but nothing helps.

Do you know how to make the frame bigger where NSIS puts the name or another solution how I can fix this?

[image: Welcome page of installer]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After finding out that NSIS_DEFINES are bugged I made a different approach and used @Anders solution:
In my CMake file I put the line

```
set(CPACK_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/)
```

pointing to the NSIS.template.in file I copied from the Cmake Modules directory into my project folder and added the lines

```
!define MUI_WELCOMEPAGE_TITLE_3LINES
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_WELCOME
...
!define MUI_FINISHPAGE_TITLE_3LINES
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_FINISH
```

It should work without copying the nsis file and using the define command, but as long as there is a bug I think this is a good compromise.

Answer (score 0):

In pure NSIS you would do:

```
!include MUI2.nsh

!define MUI_WELCOMEPAGE_TITLE_3LINES
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_WELCOME
...
!define MUI_FINISHPAGE_TITLE_3LINES
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_FINISH
```

I have no idea how you apply those defines when using cpack.

Comment: Could this be achieved somehow with nsis extra install commands?